# DynamoDb Query/Scan Expression generic "FilterExpression"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query DynamoDB using mapper.query() function with [FilterExpression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/QueryRequest.html#getFilterExpression--).
I need to generate a generic function where I will just tell the attributes operator and value, and it will return the generic string. But I see, it is not completely possible.

```
new DynamoDBQueryExpression<T>()
    .withFilterExpression("att = string_val")
```

This is possible but if I have an Integer filter, then I have to do like this :

```
new DynamoDBQueryExpression<T>()
     .withFilterExpression("att = :filter")
     .withValueMap(":filter", new AttributeValue().withN(String.valueOf(12)));
```

Can this be avoided ? I wish to put everything in the filter string.. Can dynamoDB itself recognise int/string attributes ?
Thanks in advance!